# jQuery select elements deep in the structure are not found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select elements in jQuery like this: 
 
`$("input[id*='FirstName']")` , but it's not working, it's not bringing the values I want from the page.

The input is located nested deeply inside the DOM, like the child #30 from the root, and I think jQuery is not able to find it.

Anyone faced an issue like this before??

**Update**: http://pastebin.com/es0Z1P1a

Comment: Please include sample HTML that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't it be input #FirstName since JQuery uses normal CSS rules for selecting element(s)?

Comment: @GwiddleWorker - No, because the `*=` syntax searches within the entire ID in this case. It would select inputs with the ID of FirstNameFoo, FooFirstName, and FooFirstnameFoo.

Comment: I can definitely say that depth within the page is not your problem.  It could be buried 1000 nodes deep and the browser's selection engine could still find it (provided your browser didn't run out of memory trying to render thousands of nodes)

Comment: Hello everyone, here is a link to the code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/es0Z1P1a    it's a bit long, but am trying to select elements like: dtpToDate , it's not working in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok:

```
var e = $("input[id*='dtpToDate']");
console.log(e.val()); // returns 12/10/2014
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jojc5rvw/1/

Comment: Thanks Kristoffer, it's still giving me [] , it's not retrieving anything

Answer (score 0):

You are using .NET and it's cludgy rendering system.  If you want to select .NET controls you need to write code to render the ClientID in javascript:

```
var $datePicker = $("#<%= MyDatePickerControl.ClientID %>");
```

In the code you pasted, there is nothing with the text `FirstName` in there, so you are not going to get any results with the selector `$("input[id*='FirstName']")`.

If you are trying to get all of the dtpToDate controls, you could try something like this:

```
var $datePicker = $("input[id$='dtpToDate']");
```

That selects anything that has an ID that *ends with* `dtpToDate`.

Comment: But can't I write jQuery code on the result html? as I am testing the html in chrome's developer tools, so I can't use #<%= ..

Comment: Thanks Ryan, even with  $("input[id$='dtpToDate']"); it's giving me nothing .. only this [] as a result in developer tools.

Comment: but on my environment it is.. is it something related to .net or that the code generated from server?

Comment: don't know man.  I pasted your html in jsfiddle, pasted my javascript, and it works.  You gotta figure it out from here or post a link to real working code.

Comment: that's the problem with server code stuff, you can't make it shared with others online..

Comment: Well I can't help you from here.  I can tell you that when a browser loads a DOM tree, simple CSS selectors like the one you are using will work (as evident in my fiddle).  If it's not working, you have another issue going on and the DOM tree is not getting parsed properly.  Can you right click and "inspect element", copy it's ID, and select it using `document.getElementById("ID_HERE");`